# Connecting Sony Erisson Live With Walkman with eclipse

Tags: android, sony

I have Sony Ericsson Live with Walkman. The official site does not tell about the drivers to connect with eclipse. Has anyone tried with the same.
thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm develop android with Sony Ericsson too. Just plug and play your device on Computer and it will detect automatically (on mac computer). But if you're develop with Windows machine, you must install usb driver from android website....

Comment: the problem is that android website dosen't list Live with Walkman for the drivers
I was just asking if driver of any other sonyerivsson phone will work??

Comment: yeah, I know what you mean. Download usb driver from android official website (if you developing on windows) or you dont need to install additional driver on Mac, it just work.

Comment: Please tell me how to connect sony ericsson live walkman  to pc so that it is detected in eclipse

Comment: Sorry if it too late. I think you're get it wrong. I mean open your android SDK, update your SDK and search if there's any USB driver, install it. Don't forget to enable USB Debugging on device.

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing Android on Ubuntu, [this link](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=11823740) will help you get your device recognized by the system. If you're developing on Windows, then download Sony Ericsson PC Companion from [here](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/tools/pc-companion/)

Comment: the drivers for Live with walkman are not available on the website so PC companion also dont upgrade it.

Comment: The PC companion is a universal driver updater for ALL SE phones. I've updated the link for PC companion